# strcat() has a problem in xcode using gcc

Tags: c, xcode, gcc

if I compile with XCode at the height of `strcat()` the following error is returned:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
```

while, if I compile from terminal (`gcc -Wall program.c -o Out`):

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

- `lung2` is the length of `s2`.
- `MAX` equals `30` and it is the array's maximum length.

Here is the code:

```
    char s1[MAX] = { '\0' };
    char s2[MAX] = { '\0' };
    int flag = 0;
    char *ptr;
    unsigned long int lung1, lung2 = 0;
    int verifica = 0;
    j = 0;

    ...

    while (j < lung1) {
        ptr = strstr(s1, s2);
        if (ptr) {
            strncpy(ptr, "*", lung2);
            strcat(s1, ptr + lung2);
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, your `strncpy` call says you're saying to copy zero characters? `lung2`, as mysterious a variable name as they get, is assigned `0` and never changed.

Comment: This example is far from complete. Which line causes the crash, and are you sure it's in this block? What are the pointers you're passing in? Are they within the bounds of any defined arrays? What is `MAX`? I have way more questions than answers for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code replaces each occurrence of `s2` in `s1` with an asterisk `*`.

On some platforms the behavior of `strcat` is undefined if the source and destination overlap, which is the case here since `ptr` points into `s1`.